# Grid-view in visual web-part!

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, development

I have created a visual web-part and I have a dropdown list and a gridview on it. on c# I have created a query:

```
string selected = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

       query.Query = @"<Where><Eq>
                         <FieldRef Name='Team' />
                         <Value Type='Text'>"+ selected+ @"</Value>
                      </Eq></Where>";
```

it has 3 menu: 1)small 2)medium 3)large

also in my code I have include `AutoPostBack="true"` It works fine but it is a problem for every time I change the dropdown value i.e from small to large it refreshes me the page. If I dont use this `AutoPostBack="true"` it doesn't refresh the page but it wont load the new query! Is there any way to complete this action without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the query when a submit button is pressed, or when the dropdown is changed, not on page load.

Comment: I have it running when a dropdown is changed and it refreshes my page

Comment: Where in your code is AutoPostBack true?  Is it on the dropdown?

Comment: yes it is on the dropdown in XML code

Comment: So set AutoPostBack to false on the dropdown, and create a method on dropdown change that runs the query and changes any associated values on the page.